# POST http://localhost:3000/status 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, post, routes, payment-gateway

I'm working on payment system integration with a react application. It has a redirection URL concept where the payment system will return the response.

The flow is we are initiating the payment process, it will be redirected to the payment gateway URL. Once payment gateway operations are done, it will return to the redirection URL with the response.

So while redirecting to our page, the payment system is calling the redirection URL as a POST request.

That time, this issue occurring "POST http://localhost:3000/status 404 (Not Found)".

"http://localhost:3000/status" is my redirection URL which I had given to the payment gateway system.

I could see the response in the network tab. I supposed to see some layout on this redirection page.

But on the page, it shows "Cannot POST /status". And in the console, it shows "POST http://localhost:3000/status 404 (Not Found)".

Redirection page after payment completion. [image: Redirection Page After Payment Completion]

I'm managing the router like this, where the

Contact Page - simple form to get the amount from the user, and redirecting to the payment gateway system.

Status Page - It is the redirection URL given to the payment gateway system. Supposed to show this page after the payment completion.

```
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route path='/contact'>
          <Contact />
        </Route>
        <Route 
          path='/status'>
          <Status />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Is there any way I'm missing something? Please revert back If anything I can make the question more clear. Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Are you using any backend for this application? The payment succus URL should hit your backend API URL and from this backend code, you have to call your frontend URL. Url forwarding from the backend.

Comment: We are using the KNET payment gateway service. This KNET URL has been called with required encrypted data from the frontend itself. In the KNET page, we have given the card details and all. If payment completed, KNET itself redirecting to this particular URL which we have provided with the encrypted data.

Comment: Actually, we have created redirection page with PHP now. It is working fine in PHP. But still, I need clarification on why it is not working with react js.